# Python Requests - Taking JSON data and using it in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I have a code such as this below and it's JSON code on a domain.
`{"userCount":64,"users":[{"id":"553","acid":"553","ac":"240","cs":"Le AlphaDelta","st":{"gr":false},"co":[26.93526727771073,-79.9251579421954,10667.999977505215,-163.9999997562341,-2.2288855660652414,2.4376547336953407e-7],"ve":[-0.000002161617968514662,-6.915441330619387e-7,0.000004838653476326726,0,-2.27708260122718e-10,0],"ti":1487455628374.1194,"aircraft":"240","callsign":"Le AlphaDelta","time":1487455628374.1194}`
I want python to point to this and take data from it such as I want to take cs, ac, etc. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT:
I want to take data such as the id of the first person in the json file, because there would be multiple users in the file. So I can't, therefore, have the data I had here. Basically, I want to take the data above and put it in python and split it up so in python id[1]=the id of the first user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html.

```
import json
j = json.loads('{"userCount":64,"users":[{"id":"553","acid":"553","ac":"240","cs":"Le AlphaDelta","st":{"gr":false},"co":[26.93526727771073,-79.9251579421954,10667.999977505215,-163.9999997562341,-2.2288855660652414,2.4376547336953407e-7],"ve":[-0.000002161617968514662,-6.915441330619387e-7,0.000004838653476326726,0,-2.27708260122718e-10,0],"ti":1487455628374.1194,"aircraft":"240","callsign":"Le AlphaDelta","time":1487455628374.1194}')
print j['ac']
```

Comment: What if I wanted to take data from it like ac without having the id and such.

Comment: You can do something like: `for i in j['users']: print i['ac']` the all ac should be printed

Comment: I got this error with that 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\yah.py", line 4, in <module>
    for i in j['users']:
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable'

Comment: You added python-2.7 as tag for you question. But you traceback says Python36

Answer (score 0):

Your json text seems not to be well formed:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{"userCount":64,"users":[{"id":"553","acid":"553","ac":"240","cs":"Le AlphaDelta","st":{"gr":false},"co":[26.93526727771073,-79.9251579421954,10667.999977505215,-163.9999997562341,-2.2288855660652414,2.4376547336953407e-7],"ve":[-0.000002161617968514662,-6.915441330619387e-7,0.000004838653476326726,0,-2.27708260122718e-10,0],"ti":1487455628374.1194,"aircraft":"240","callsign":"Le AlphaDelta","time":1487455628374.1194}')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 422 (char 421)
```

Got it:

```
>>> import json
>>> j = json.loads('{"userCount":64,"users":[{"id":"553","acid":"553","ac":"240","cs":"Le AlphaDelta","st":{"gr":false},"co":[26.93526727771073,-79.9251579421954,10667.999977505215,-163.9999997562341,-2.2288855660652414,2.4376547336953407e-7],"ve":[-0.000002161617968514662,-6.915441330619387e-7,0.000004838653476326726,0,-2.27708260122718e-10,0],"ti":1487455628374.1194,"aircraft":"240","callsign":"Le AlphaDelta","time":1487455628374.1194}]}')
>>> print j['users']
[{u'ac': u'240', u'co': [26.93526727771073, -79.9251579421954, 10667.999977505215, -163.9999997562341, -2.2288855660652414, 2.4376547336953407e-07], u've': [-2.161617968514662e-06, -6.915441330619387e-07, 4.838653476326726e-06, 0, -2.27708260122718e-10, 0], u'time': 1487455628374.1194, u'st': {u'gr': False}, u'aircraft': u'240', u'callsign': u'Le AlphaDelta', u'ti': 1487455628374.1194, u'cs': u'Le AlphaDelta', u'acid': u'553', u'id': u'553'}]
>>> print j['users'][0]['ac']
240
>>> print j['users'][0]['cs']
Le AlphaDelta
```